# Extract statistics from Anderson-Darling test (list)

Tags: r, lapply

I would like to extract the p-values from the Anderson-Darling test (ad.test from package kSamples). The test result is a list of 12 containing a 2x3 matrix. The p value is part of the 2x3 matrix and is present in element 7.

When using the following code:

```
lapply(AD_result,  "[[", 7)
```

I get the following subset of AD test results (first 2 of a total of 50 shown)

```
[[1]]
             AD    T.AD  asympt. P-value
version 1: 1.72 0.94536          0.13169
version 2: 1.51 0.66740          0.17461

[[2]]
               AD   T.AD  asympt. P-value
version 1: 12.299 14.624       6.9248e-07
version 2: 11.900 14.144       1.1146e-06
```

My question is how to extract only the p-value (e.g. from version 1) and put these 50 results into a vector

The output from `str(AD_result)` is:

```
List of 55
 $ :List of 12
  ..$ test.name : chr "Anderson-Darling"
  ..$ k         : int 2
  ..$ ns        : int [1:2] 103 2905
  ..$ N         : int 3008
  ..$ n.ties    : int 2873
  ..$ sig       : num 0.762
  ..$ ad        : num [1:2, 1:3] 1.72 1.51 0.945 0.667 0.132 ...
  .. ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. .. ..$ : chr [1:2] "version 1:" "version 2:"
  .. .. ..$ : chr [1:3] "AD" "T.AD" " asympt. P-value"
  ..$ warning   : logi FALSE
  ..$ null.dist1: NULL
  ..$ null.dist2: NULL
  ..$ method    : chr "asymptotic"
  ..$ Nsim      : num 1
  ..- attr(*, "class")= chr "kSamples"
```

Comment: I think you need to provide some example data, or at least provide the output from `str(AD_result)`, to get some good answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try:

```
unlist(lapply(AD_result, function(x) x$ad[,3]))
```